# React-native-firebase Database - Retrieve datas from nested calls

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, promise, react-native-firebase

I have a Firebase database as such (for instance):

```
{
    'itemCategories': [
        _categoryKey1: {
            name: 'Category 1'
        },
        _categoryKey2: {
            name: 'Category 2'
        },
        _categoryKey3: {
            name: 'Category 3'
        },
    ],
    'items': [
        _itemKey1: {
            categoryId: '_categoryKey1',
            name: 'Item 1',
        }
        _itemKey2: {
            categoryId: '_categoryKey2',
            name: 'Item 2',
        }
        _itemKey3: {
            categoryId: '_categoryKey1',
            name: 'Item 3',
        }
        _itemKey4: {
            categoryId: '_categoryKey3',
            name: 'Item 4',
        }
        _itemKey5: {
            categoryId: '_categoryKey3',
            name: 'Item 5',
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to get is an array of items grouped by categories, as such:

```
itemList = [
    {
        category: 'Category 1',
        items: [
            {
                id: '_itemKey1',
                categoryId: '_categoryKey1',
                name: 'Item 1',
            },
            {
                id: '_itemKey3',
                categoryId: '_categoryKey1',
                name: 'Item 3',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        category: 'Category 2',
        items: [
            {
                id: '_itemKey2',
                categoryId: '_categoryKey2',
                name: 'Item 2',
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        category: 'Category 3',
        items: [
            {
                id: '_itemKey4',
                categoryId: '_categoryKey3',
                name: 'Item 4',
            },
            {
                id: '_itemKey5',
                categoryId: '_categoryKey3',
                name: 'Item 5',
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I use a `react-redux` action to achieve this, like so:

```
export const setItemList = (list) => {
    return {
        type: 'setItemList',
        value: list
    }
}

export const getItemListByCategory = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {

        let itemList = []

        firebase.database().ref('itemCategories').on('value', (snapCategory) => {
            snapCategory.forEach((category) => {
                const categoryId = category.key

                firebase.database().ref('items').orderByChild('categoryId').equalTo(categoryId).on('value', (snapItem) => {
                    let items = []
                    snapItem.forEach((item) => {
                        items.push({
                            id: item.key,
                            ...item.val()
                        })
                    })

                    itemList.push({
                        category: category.val().name,
                        items: items
                    })

                    // This is where I think is the issue
                    dispatch(setItemList(itemList))
                })
            })

            // The dispatch should be there, when every calls resolved
        })
    }
}
```

This works pretty well, *for the most part*.
As I'm in a `forEach` loop, I will retrieve datas category by category, and actually dispatch multiple **partial** `itemList` until the `forEach` loop ends.
Obviously, I'd prefer to wait until the loop ends **then** dispatch the complete `itemList`.

I can't figure out how to wait for the loop to end - and all the calls to resolve.
I feel like I should work with `Promise` but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Promise.all()?
Instead of triggering dispatch in `firebase.database().ref('items').orderByChild('categoryId').equalTo(categoryId).on`
You could add this call to a promises array. Something like this:

```
const promises = [];

snapCategory.foreach(snap => {

   promises.push(your calls here, instead of dispatch return the list here)
}) 

Promise.all(promises).then((...args) => {
// args should contain all lists here, you can manipulate them as you need
// and dispatch afterwards
})
```